# Is it possible to programmatically get the identifier of a basic UIViewController from an UIViewController or Storyboard in Swift/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, storyboard

I know that we can instantiate a particular UIViewController basing on its identifier (see below):

```
var myPageContentViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as PageContentViewController
```

But my question doesn't concern that point, in other words I just would like to know if it would be possible to programmatically (in the source code) retrieve the identifier (in our case the string value "A") that I set in the storyboard for this particular PageContentViewController (which is a subclass of UIViewController in my project)?

Note: an answer using the Swift development language instead of the Objective-C development language would be more convenient for me, even if I know the latter. For your information, I use the 6.0.1 version of Xcode.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Swift:

```
 var str: String! = self.restorationIdentifier
```

Comment: Make sure in storyboard, you've marked "Use Storyboard ID" in identity inspector for respective view controller.

Comment: @Sikander Why? we just want story board id, that's it. Why we mark Use Storyboard ID?

Comment: @King-Wizard Why? we just want story board id, that's it. Why we mark Use Storyboard ID?

Comment: You can't _have_ the storyboard ID. It's internal to the storyboard. That's why everybody wants you to check "Use Storyboard ID" in the storyboard. That way they match. Unfortunately, I can't get a restoration ID for a view controller loaded with `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)`.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the identifier of the `UIViewController` by using the restoration identifier with the following code in objective C:

```
NSString *restorationId = self.restorationIdentifier;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

With `restorationIdentifier` you can get the nil value. There is another way to get the `UIViewController` identifier, try this

```
let identifier = String(describing: MyViewController)
```

But you need to give the same identifier on the storyboard as your `UIViewController` class name.
Please check below example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Check "Use Storyboard ID" in the storyboard inspector for the respective view controller.
2. Use the following code:

### Swift:

```
let restorationIdentifier = self.restorationIdentifier
```

### Objective-C:

```
NSString *restorationIdentifier = self.restorationIdentifier;
```