# how to get a viewcontroller's storyboard id/name

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

In my app, there are three storyboard. What I'd like to know is how to get a storyboard id/name in a viewcontroller code since UIStoryBoard init func takes first parameter name: String. where it stored and how to access it?

Comment: `UIViewController` have `storyboard: UIStoryboard?` property from which the view controller originated. Do you looking for it or for something else?

Comment: class UIStoryboard does not have a property or method to get it's name/id.in Swift. Or maybe I miss soemthing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to programmatically get the identifier of a basic UIViewController from an UIViewController or Storyboard in Swift/Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229355/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-get-the-identifier-of-a-basic-uiviewcontrolle)

Answer (score 5):

The storyboard name is the name of the .storyboard file itself, but without the .storyboard extension.

The `UIViewController`'s storyboard ID cannot be gotten, unless you have the restoration ID set to the storyboard ID and then you use

```
self.restorationIdentifier
```

Comment: @user584819 Edited my post.

Comment: I got nil when I try print(self.restorationIdentifier) inside of viewDidLoad()

Comment: @user584819 In the interface builder, is the "Use storyboard ID" checked?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get thestoryboard's name without using private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of a storyboard, just go to your storyboard file, and don't click on any of the View Controllers. Open up the File Inspector, and on the first tab, at the top it will have your name (ie. "Main.storyboard"). It's also just the file name typically. However, the best way to get at a storyboard is just to get at the `storyboard` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.title` to get the name of the ViewController